# Round down time to last 5 minutes

Tags: java, time, rounding

I want to round down to the last 5 minutes in my code but it's not working:

```
Date whateverDateYouWant = new Date();
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(whateverDateYouWant);
int unroundedMinutes = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int mod = unroundedMinutes % 5;
calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -(mod < 3 ? -mod : (5-mod)));
SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
String formattedDate = format1.format(calendar.getTime());
```

So if it's 08:16 it should be 08:15 if it's 09:49 it should be 09:45 and if it's 12:00 it should round down to 11:55.

Comment: *...if it's 12:00 it should round down to 11:55.* - What if it's 12:04? Should it result in 11:55 because you want 12:00 to be converted into 11:55?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -(mod < 3 ? -mod : (5-mod)));
```

With this:

```
calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, unroundedMinutes == 0 ? -5 : -mod);
```